# How to open a file in WMP 11 by command line without playing it?

Tags: command-line, windows-media-player

I need to open a file in "standby" mode from a shortcut, wait for an introduction speech and then play the file.

How can I open the file in Windows Media Player 11 by command-line without playing it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/241422) you can use /open in Windows Media Player 6.4, but it seems that the command line options [have since changed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd562624(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: The `/open` option does not work any more. Answer should be deleted.

Answer (score 4):

You can make a .bat/.cmd file with a pause statement. At the end of the intro you can then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and the video will start. Here's an example:

```
@echo off
echo Tested on Windows 7 64-bit
pause 
start /d "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Media Player" wmplayer.exe "C:\Users\Username\Videos\GTA 4\test.avi"
```

Comment: Not exactly an answer to that question, but a nice idea!

Answer (score 0):

Simply type the song name as `music.mp3`.

If there is any space in songs name just write it as `"music new.mp3"`. Here, `music` stands for the title of the song you wanted to play.

Comment: No, doing this will barely open the .mp3 into WMPlayer because it will open the file in default media player. In most systems, WMPlayer is not the default and has a lot of better alternatives.