# How can I open a video file with Windows Media Player without playing it automatically

Tags: windows-media-player

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to open a file in WMP 11 by command line without playing it?](https://superuser.com/questions/195055/how-to-open-a-file-in-wmp-11-by-command-line-without-playing-it)

I'd like to open a .avi file in Media Player, but I don't want to let it start playing automatically.